# Rake aborted - NoMethodError: undefined methor 'deep_symbolize_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have an App in Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to deploy it on a server. I'm using Capistrano to automatize processes but I got an error while doing 'cap production deploy', that I have no ideia how to resolve. Do you know how to fix it?

Thks in advance!

[image]

Comment: you're probably passing a string in a line of your `/config/environment.rb` somewhere where it's expecting a hash

Comment: No, im not passing anything. Thks